# Direction of PC1 and PC2 in Principal Component Analysis (PCA)

Tags: pca

I am a bit confused by what is considered the direction for the principal
components in PCA.

For example: I do understand that the picture on the right hand side is correct.

However, is the the PC1 direction just the northeast pointing arrow (i.e. direction is of increasing axis value) or is it double ended (e.g. it also includes a south west pointing arrow at the other end of the line?

I have seen explanations for PC1 with no arrows, one arrow, and two arrows, so it's just a bit confusing which is considered the PC1 direction.

[image: PC1 and PC2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a step back: what is the first sample principal component?

It is the linear combination $\mathbf a_1^\top \mathbf y$ that maximizes the corresponding sample variance $\mathbf a_1^\top\mathbf S\mathbf a_1$ subject to $\mathbf a_1^\top\mathbf a_1 =1.$

The second principal component? The same definition as above with the added condition that $\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf a_1^\top\mathbf y, \mathbf a_2^\top \mathbf y) =0;$ the latter implying $\mathbf a_1^\top\mathbf a_2=0$ that is, they are orthogonal (not to be confused with being independent).

Geometrically (cf.$\rm [I]$), the first PC is the shortest principal axis of the biggest ellipsoid in the family  $\mathbf a_1^\top\mathbf S\mathbf a_1$ that touches the hypersphere $\mathbf a_1^\top\mathbf a_1=1.$ This effectively is equivalent to finding a set of basis vectors that $\mathbf S$ acts on simply by "expanding" (contracting). That is nothing but $\mathbf S$' (normalized) eigenvectors.

Finding the PCs is tantamount to rotation to the new coordinates that are the principal axes of the hyperellipsoid or "*the natural axes of the **swarm of points***" (cf. $\rm [II]$). So, can you infer finally what the geometrical picture entails?

Also, an eigenvector has only one direction (that's basic concept - divide its component by its norm to get the unit vector) and so, I didn't get why it's difficult to get a sense of the direction of first PC - this would correspond to the largest principal axis of the family  $\mathbf a_1^\top\mathbf S^{-1}\mathbf a_1.$

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ A Geometric Approach to Principal Components Analysis, *Michael Stuart,* The American Statistician, $36:4,~ 365-367.$

$\rm [II]$ Methods of Multivariate Analysis, *Alvin C. Rencher,* John Wiley & Sons., $2002, $ sec. $12.2.1, $ p. $381.$